# Button click - NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Tags: android

how can i fix this error..? this is about many circumstances that be processed when we press in a submit button...(android)
we have a page with many data that user can set them to custom mode, and all of data is gonna be save in a row of table in a database. nothing shouldn't be empty and I consider for every empty data an error that warn user to fill them...please help me to find out when this error maybe happened.what was my mistake?

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: mizco.project_one, PID: 7092

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                     at 
java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                                                                     at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                     at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
                                                                     at 
mizco.project_one.add_pole_coppn$1.onClick(add_pole_coppn.java:459)
                                                                     at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                     at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                                                                     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may occure when you do like this

```
String stringNumber = "";
int number = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
```

You can do like this:

```
String stringNumber = "";
if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(stringNumber)) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
} else {
    //warn user
}
```

or this:

```
String stringNumber = "";
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
} catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
    //warn user
}
```

Comment: And the solution is to...?